# "atomic constraint depends on itself" error when compiling iterator in C++23

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++23

I'm trying to make an iterator that passes over a string view mostly character-by-character with a few special cases and what I tried was the following:

```cpp
// iter.hpp
#include <string_view>

typedef std::basic_string_view<char> UStringView;

class symbol_iter
{
private:
  UStringView str;
  UStringView::size_type sloc = 0;
  UStringView::size_type eloc = 0;
public:
  symbol_iter(UStringView s);
  symbol_iter(const symbol_iter& other);
  ~symbol_iter();
  UStringView operator*();
  symbol_iter& operator++();
  bool operator!=(const symbol_iter& other) const;
  bool operator==(const symbol_iter& other) const;
  symbol_iter begin();
  symbol_iter end();
};

symbol_iter::symbol_iter(UStringView s) : str(s)
{
  ++*this;
}

symbol_iter::symbol_iter(const symbol_iter& other)
  : str(other.str), sloc(other.sloc), eloc(other.eloc) {}

symbol_iter::~symbol_iter() {}

UStringView symbol_iter::operator*() {
  return str.substr(sloc, eloc-sloc);
}

symbol_iter& symbol_iter::operator++()
{
  if (sloc < str.size()) {
    sloc = eloc;
    eloc++;
    char c = str[sloc];
    if (c == '\\') {
      sloc++;
      eloc++;
    } else if (c == '<') {
      for (auto i = eloc; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == '>') {
          eloc = i + 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (eloc > str.size()) eloc = str.size();
  }
  return *this;
}

bool symbol_iter::operator!=(const symbol_iter& o) const
{
  return str != o.str || sloc != o.sloc || eloc != o.eloc;
}

bool symbol_iter::operator==(const symbol_iter& o) const
{
  return str == o.str && sloc == o.sloc && eloc == o.eloc;
}

symbol_iter symbol_iter::begin()
{
  return symbol_iter(str);
}

symbol_iter symbol_iter::end()
{
  symbol_iter ret(str);
  ret.sloc = str.size();
  ret.eloc = str.size();
  return ret;
}

// main.cc
#include "iter.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  UStringView name(argv[1]);
  for (auto sym : symbol_iter(name)) {
    std::cout << sym << std::endl;
  }
}
```

When I compile this under C++2a, it does exactly what I expect:

```
$ g++ --std=c++2a main.cc
$ ./a.out 'xyz<q>'
x
y
z
<q>
```

but when I compile with C++23, I get the error

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:574:21: error: satisfaction of atomic constraint ‘requires(_Tp& __t) {std::ranges::__cust::begin(__t);std::ranges::__cust::end(__t);} [with _Tp = _Range]’ depends on itself
  574 |     concept range = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  575 |       {
      |       ~              
  576 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  577 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  578 |       };
      |       ~
```

and I have not been able to find any explanation of this error by googling.

The loop in `main` shows how I have been using it (range-for loops with `auto`), though the error appears even if I remove the loop (that is, even if nothing else in the code refers to the `symbol_iter` class at all).

Additionally, the error is fixed if I change `UStringView` to `UStringView*` everywhere except `operator*` (I tried this because elsewhere in the codebase there is an iterator with an identical interface except that the input type is a pointer rather than a view).

Comment: `symbol_iter` doesn't make sense. It is a range, so why are you treating it like its an iterator (with `operator*` and `++` and the like)?

Comment: What happens if you make your `begin` and `end` members const?

Comment: changing `begin` and `end` to `const` doesn't change the error message

Comment: It would help if you showed code that actually produces the error; clearly when you compile _this_ under C++2a it doesn't compile either, as it is incomplete. A MCVE goes a long way towards getting help.

Comment: @ildjarn - done, though as noted in the updated post, the calling code is not the site of the error.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can't use a range in this instance because one of the requirements of the project is that it also compile under C++17.

Comment: @popcorndude: That doesn't answer my question. `symbol_iter` has `begin/end` functions in principle. That makes it a range. But it also has iterator functionality. And `operator*` returns a value type (which means it's a proxy iterator, and that's going to cause problems for C++17, but whatever) that is another one of these objects. So... what is this type *doing*? It seems very confused; it's hard to know what is going wrong when the type just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to iterate over a string by character, except for things in angle brackets, which I want returned as a single unit, as shown in the loop in `main` and in the command line output.

Comment: @popcorndude: You're missing the trees for the forest. Like, I get the broad idea of what your goal is. What I don't understand is why you decided to make a type that is both a range and an iterator into its own range. `vector::iterator` is not *also* a `vector`; you can't call `begin` on a `vector::iterator`. Do you understand why that's weird? Your compiler is complaining either because something in your strange type confused it or it has a bug that was triggered by your strange type.

Comment: I was assuming that the underlying string view was the relevant range.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. https://godbolt.org/z/KaWE6M1fh

Comment: Fails with GCC 12.1 and earlier, works with 12.2 and trunk (and latest clang/libc++, and MSVC). So, seems to be a bug that's already been fixed.

Comment: [Here is repro](https://godbolt.org/z/hq57jhrW7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear, based on the comments from ildjarn and 康桓瑋 that this is a bug in a prior version of GCC.

The more fundamental problem, which I think Nicol Bolas was trying to point out (and which I did not understand the first few times), is that I shouldn't try to create multiple iterator types for a single class (much as I would like to), a mistake that hadn't been caught before because it happened to be the case that my prior attempts at writing iterators didn't break anything.

The class which now works on both compiler versions is

```cpp
class symbol_iter
{
private:
  UStringView str;
public:
  symbol_iter(UStringView s) : str(s) {}
  ~symbol_iter() {}
  class iterator
  {
    friend symbol_iter;
  private:
    UStringView str;
    UStringView::size_type sloc = 0;
    UStringView::size_type eloc = 0;
  public:
    iterator(UStringView s);
    iterator(const iterator& other);
    ~iterator();
    UStringView operator*() const;
    iterator& operator++();
    bool operator!=(const symbol_iter::iterator& other) const;
    bool operator==(const symbol_iter::iterator& other) const;
  };
  iterator begin() const;
  iterator end() const;
};
```

Comment: `"I shouldn't try to create multiple iterator types for a single class`" - actually, that's a completely normal thing to do. Many containers have both `iterator` and `const_iterator`. What Nicol Bolas was saying is that an iterator is **not** a range, and so an iterator should **not** have its own `begin()`/`end()` methods.